# Spring Security.config - cannot get login page to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a webapp and I am using Spring Security. I have my Spring Security `configure` function in `security.config` as:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/settings/api/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
}
```

The problem I am having is this always gets mapped to `@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)` instead of `@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)`. So whenever I am trying to retrieve username and password from Http Request it comes out as `null`. How do I get it to map to `POST` method?

I have my post controller as

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    boolean f = false;
    f = customAuthenticationProvider.verifyUser(username,password,request);
    if(f == false) 
        return "loginError";
    else
        return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with formlogin() you don't have to provide the POST controller, that's being taken care of by spring on the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. What you are configuring it's just the loginPage("/login") on which you have to add a form with a POST action to "/login", and add username and password inputs.

Something like this:

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i just added my post controller as you can see i am calling a function from inside that so i don't think what you suggested will work . i am very new to this so any help would be nice .Thanks

Comment: It works as I tell you, check this out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

Comment: Thanks . It isn't working though . maybe i have a problem somewhere else . I will update once i find it .

Comment: Hey , I have tried almost everything and still it doesn't gets matched to the post controller , Any general reasonsas to why this can happen ??

Comment: @Ulises, the link you provided is broken